# Call NSString in UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, uialertview

hey I'm coding using theos and I want the value of an NSString to display inside of the fields on the UIAlertView below, how would i go about writing that? here it is:

```
UIAlertView *quickreply = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"%@" message:@"%@" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"Reply", nil];
```

I've tried writing a , NSStringID after the quotes but it gives errors for the entire UIAlertView, so idk how I'm supposed to code it, am i supposed to use brackets or more quotes within the quotes, or parenthesis' or what?

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myIvar];
```

set the message of the UIAlertView to the message NSString

Comment: yea thats what MSgambel suggested, but i think just setting them without the @"" and just the NSString ID will work, for example
`initWithTitle:sender message:message` i haven't been able to test it yet though

Answer (score 2):

stringWithFormat is what you want, try this:

```
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title is %@", @"my title"];
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"message is %@", @"my message"];
UIAlertView *quickreply = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"Reply", nil];
```

Comment: i probably should have mentioned this but the strings are already defined from a different header

Comment: @iGamers, can you provide more code and the description of the question?

Comment: im pulling strings from the CTMessage header from the CoreTelephony Framework, the two strings I'm calling are sender and message, which will provide the incoming SMS sender name or number, and the sms body, i think your code will work fine once i get the header to work correctly, but when i compile using theos it says the header gives me errors, i haven't touched anything on it though

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", theString];
```

if you want to do it that way. Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for the quick response, but I'm getting some errors with the framework header for some reason
also, i think that code may be giving me errors  
  
Tweak.xm:20: error: expected identifier before ‘[’ token
Tweak.xm:20: error: objective-c++ message argument(s) are expected before ‘[’ token
Tweak.xm:20: error: expected `]' before ‘[’ token
Tweak.xm:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘alloc’
Tweak.xm:20: error: expected `]' before ‘alloc’
Tweak.xm:20: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘alloc’
Tweak.xm:20: error: ‘message’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @iGamers: That is completely unrelated to your original question. Please make a new question post if you want help with those errors.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: the errors are actually related to the bit of code he suggested, it does have to do with it

Comment: @iGamers: If you're getting build errors that are referring to the header files of a framework you're linking against, then this snippet is irrelevant.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: but the errors i posted are about the code he suggested, i just mentioned the framework header issue, i didn't specify anything else on it, just informational purposes, thats why i said "also, i think that code may be giving me errors"